Unpersist on parentDF impact on persisted and computed childDF
As part of Pyspark - unpersisting parent dataframe removes also the child dataframe from the cache, It is mentioned that if we unpersist a parentDF then all the childDF will also get unpersisted.
I am observing different behviour of unpersist in local.  If I unpersist the parentDF, then childDF are still cached.
1.  val inputPath = "C:\\code\\Test\\SparkTest\\weather.parquet"
2.  val parentDF = sparkSession.read.parquet(inputPath).persist()
3.  parentDF.show(false)      // At this point parentDF will be computed and persisted
4.  val childDF = parentDF.filter("RainTomorrow == 'Yes'").persist()
5.  childDF.show(false)       // At this point childDF will be computed and persisted
6.  parentDF.unpersist()      // Unpersisting the parentDF
7.  val grandChildDF = childDF.filter("RainToday == 'Yes'")
8.  grandChildDF.show(false)  // At this point, in yarn-ui, childDF is still there.

Check current Yarn UI - https://i.sstatic.net/269tsfXM.png
I want to understand the correct behaviour of persist and unpersist method.

The point is, a cascading unpersist only happens in Spark when your child dataframe is not cached separately.
I can see you did:
val childDF = parentDF.filter("RainTomorrow == 'Yes'").persist()

Now the question is when a persistence happens for a dataframe?

If you are calling persistence() explicitly, then the childDF will persist in a separate memory block, and will not unpersist even if you unpersist the parentDF.


All you need to do is remove persist() from childDF like below:
val childDF = parentDF.filter("RainTomorrow == 'Yes'")

